# Dynamic Email Signature

Tags: javascript, email, outlook, placeholder, signature

No idea if this is a dumb question.

I want to code a dynamic email signature for everyone in my organization. Rather than make one for every individual, can I not access our Outlook database of names/emails and use some kind of dynamic placeholder using JS? This is not unlike what Mailchimp does, for example, by filling in the receiver's first name using a placeholder. So I'd like to write a single code snippet that fills in their name and maybe their title. Would I have to use Microsoft's REST API?

Comment: This question might be off-topic, but if you're using Office 365, check out this article on how to do something similar to what you're asking: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/create-signatures-and-disclaimers?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Outlook supports using variables. So there isn't really a need for javascript. Googling "Outlook signature variables" should yield some results, that should help.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) for setting signatures for OWA. But, in general, email signatures are stored by the Outlook client, not within the mailbox. This is why users see different signatures across desktop, mobile, and web clients.

The only settings like this available via Graph are settings stored at the mailbox level. These are accessed via `mailboxSettings` object: `automaticRepliesSetting`, `language`, `timeZone`, and `workingHours`.

You may also find the following github repo helpful: https://github.com/GruberMarkus/Set-OutlookSignatures.